# How can you identify all nodes that use a certain paragraph type or template?

Tags: 7, nodes, paragraphs

In Drupal 7, given a custom paragraph bundle and an associated template file, is there a way to list all the nodes using that bundle? Or, if it's any easier, a way to do the same for a specific module instead of a paragraph type?

A Drupal core module update (https://www.drupal.org/project/link/issues/3095484) broke a bunch of our links across our site, and while a workaround is available, I wanted to test it against all the existing nodes first.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) What have you tried so far? Entity field query? Do you know how to write a custom module? Please edit your question and add your current approach or code that is not working. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [runwithscissors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/96788/runswithscissors) suggested in his comment, this can achieved with a view.

1. Create a view that shows nodes
2. Add a relationship to the referenced paragraphs
3. Add a filter on the paragraph bundle (aka 'Paragraph Type')

Once the relationship is added, the bundle fields will be available as filter.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I realized I was mistaken in my original question... what was needed was a way to list all instances of a certain field type (link), rather than nodes and paragraphs. That was my bad, and I will start another question for that. Thank you!